# Why doesn't localhost work anymore? (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, localhost

So I accidentally used next build and now for some reason when I try to spin up a server on local host (npm start) to see changes I make it doesn't work anymore.

Local host 3000 works but when I make changes to the code nothing seems to change on local host.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are viewing the "built" version of the site from the .next folder, and not the version that is being served from the code you are editing.

Try running `next dev` to run your app in development mode.

See [here](https://nextjs.org/docs) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .next folder and try npm run dev command. It helped me